# should I re-install python again for zlib module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zlib, distribute

When installing distribute-0.6.49 with python3.3.2 in Ubuntu system, error encountered

....blablabla followed by...

```
"Compression requires the (missing) zlib module")
RuntimeError: Compression requires the (missing) zlib module
```

I have checked previous solutions that I need to install zlib package, but Should I re install my python again before that? can't I install zlib over it?

If re-installing of python needed, Where can I find python 3.3 with zlib already therein so that i can install python as usual?

Comment: Was python installed from source or from a Ubuntu package?

Comment: from source, ubuntu by default had python 2.7, but i did python 3.3.2 from source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running ubuntu then it is usually recomended that you use the package from the package manager.  You can get python 3 - currently 3.3.1 with either `sudo apt-get install python3` *if I recall correctly* or by using the software centre.

I am reasonably sure that the default distribution includes zlib.

```
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:30:32) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zlib
>>> exit()
```

Comment: in python3.3.1, zlib is already available?

Answer (score 2):

To compile Python with `zlib` support, you need to install the [`zlib1g-dev` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/zlib1g-dev) so that Python can find the headers.

You'd need to re-install your source-compiled Python to take this along.

Comment: you mean first I should install zlib1g-dev package separately before python , then install python version?

Comment: Yes; the python configure script won't be able to find the zlib include files otherwise.

Comment: is that? I already did tis just now, but still cant import zlib

Comment: No, that is not what I said. Use the Ubuntu package manager to install `zlib1g-dev`, then `cd Python-3.3.0`, `./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3`, `make`, `sudo make install`.

Comment: If you installed `zlib` from source too, you'd need to add the headers location to the python configure call; with the Ubuntu package that's not needed (as the headers can then be found in a standard location).

Comment: would this [zlib_1.2.3.3.dfsg.orig.tar.gz] version of zlib would be fine for python3.3.1 or 3.3.2 version?

Comment: Turns out I answered this exact same question before, see the proposed dupe.

Comment: Install the `zlib1g-dev` package for *your* version of Ubuntu. 1.2.3.3 is fine.

Comment: Don't install all the dependencies from source. *There is no point in doing that* as the versions in Ubuntu are plenty new and *maintained*.

Comment: Otherwise, use `./configure -with-zlib=/path/to/directory/with/zlib/header/files`.

Comment: The above dupe is when installing zlib, right? in the zlib package directory.

Comment: No, the dupe is for when you are installing Python 3 from source and `zlib` can not be imported. **There is no need to install `zlib` from source**. There is no good reason to do so. Don't do it.

Comment: I linked to the package in my answer. Pick the right version (there are links for lucid, precise, etc.), then the right platform (amd64 or i386); the latter link to the mirror list for downloading. Download the `.deb` file,  and use `dpkg -i filename.deb` to install.

Comment: Finally I have zlib. I installed latest ubuntu 13.04, already available there. Thanks though. Helped me to learn